# Copy read-only Unix files

Tags: unix, permissions, winscp

My teacher created a subdirectory that has a bunch of very lengthy .pl files he wants us to use to test our code on. I usually just xfer any files I need through WinSCP, but I don't have permissions to do that in this case. I think he made his directory private and just created the subdirectory for us to access. I tried to just do cntrl+space to mark the file, then scroll down and cntrl+c into a notepad file.. but cntrl+space is not marking because it's a read-only file.

Thanks for the help, and sorry if this question has an easy fix. I'm new to unix and couldn't find the answer online.

Comment: That's what I thought too, just assumed I was doing something wrong. Thanks for your advice and the link. I didn't know about that site.

Comment: Figured it out: cp -R * locationDir